# How to get corners of a traced image?

Tags: java, image, opencv, edge-detection

I am trying to use edge detecction to find 4 corners of a scanned paper, so i can crop it out. Here is what code I have, but it does not detect the points correctly. I am trying to do this without OpenCV.

```
        detectEdges(image);
        HashMap<Integer, Integer> corners = new HashMap<>();
        HashMap<Integer, Integer> reverseCorners = new HashMap<>();


        int white = new Color(255, 255, 255).getRGB();
        int red = new Color(255, 0, 0).getRGB();
        int Blue = new Color(0, 0, 255).getRGB();
        for (int i = 2; i < image.getWidth() - 2; i++) {
            for (int j = 2; j < image.getHeight() - 2; j++) {
                int color = image.getRGB(i, j);
                int right = image.getRGB(i + 1, j);
                int left = image.getRGB(i - 1, j);
                int top = image.getRGB(i, j + 1);
                int bottom = image.getRGB(i, j - 1);
                int rightCheck = image.getRGB(i + 2, j);
                int leftCheck = image.getRGB(i - 2, j);
                int topCheck = image.getRGB(i, j + 2);
                int bottomCheck = image.getRGB(i, j - 2);


                if (color == white) {
                    //TR Corner
                    boolean isCornerLR = (((right != white && rightCheck != white) && (left == white && leftCheck == white)) || ((left != white && leftCheck != white) && (right == white && rightCheck == white)));
                    boolean isCornerTD = (((top != white && topCheck != white) && (bottom == white && bottomCheck == white)) || ((bottom != white && bottomCheck != white) && (top == white && topCheck == white)));
                    if (isCornerLR && isCornerTD) {

                        corners.put(i, j);
                        image.setRGB(i, j, red);


                    }
                }

            }
        }

        HashMap<Integer, Integer> extremeCorners = new HashMap<>();
        /*Get opposite corners of shape. so, Bottom left to Top Right, or Top Left to Bottom Right
        for case one, (LowKey,LowValue), (HighKey, HighKeyValue). Case two - (LowKey,HighValue),(HighKey,LowValue)
        */
        List<Integer> valueOfValue = new ArrayList<>(corners.values());
        for (int a : corners.keySet()) {
            reverseCorners.put(corners.get(a), a);
        }
        Collections.sort(valueOfValue);
        int yCorner1 = valueOfValue.get(valueOfValue.size() - 1);
        int yCorner2 = valueOfValue.get(0);
        int xCorner1 = reverseCorners.get(yCorner1);
        int xCorner2 = reverseCorners.get(yCorner2);
        System.out.println(corners);



        extremeCorners.put(xCorner1, yCorner1);
        image.setRGB(xCorner1, yCorner1, Blue);
        image.setRGB(xCorner2, yCorner2, Blue);
        extremeCorners.put(xCorner2, yCorner2);


        File f = new File("EdgeImages/" + name);
        ImageIO.write(image, "png", f);
        return extremeCorners;

    }
```

So what this code does, is that it looks for potential corners and marks them with red and adds them to a hashmap, which is pretty accurate in getting potential corners. from there, I tried to make another hashmap that stored 2 corners. This is where the code doesn't work, I am sure it is my logic which is the error, but I am not sure how to proceed from here.

Attached below is the image

[image]

Comment: Here's a [link](https://muthu.co/harris-corner-detector-implementation-in-python/) for corner harris detector implementation in python from scratch. It may be helpfull.

Comment: Oh ok, I am trying to do this without external libraries as the such, but if it comes down to it, I will do it. I was originally trying to get the extreme values in the hashmap as a corner.

Comment: Searching for lines (fitting) and their intersections is more accurate.

Comment: About that, when an edge isn't a straight line, the y and x will be offset by some pixels. This makes drawing a line with intersections impossible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Low accuracy solution:

Consider the blob formed by the outline and scan its pixels (the contour pixels can do). For every pixel, compute the values of X+Y and X-Y, and keep a trace of the pixels that yield the minimum and maximum of these quantities. These are the four corners. It might be that the outline is split in several pieces, and it suffices to use the pixels of all pieces.

High accuracy solution:

Using the above method, find the corners, roughly and draw the two diagonals. Then classify the pixels as belonging to one of the quadrants defined by these diagonals. It is advisable to discard the pixels close to the corners, as their classification is unsure.

Finally, fit a straight line on the four subsets of points, using your favorite line fitting method.

[image]

Comment: Yeah, I did something along the lines of that. I used the distance formula, whichever point gives the greatest distance is a corner, but thank you for the solution!

Comment: @Mischef9:  the distance criterion will work as well, though you need to find local maxima, and this is less easy than one might think. I am offering you a method with four global ones.

Comment: Yeah, you are right. I appreciate the solution, but I am not too sure how to implement this, so I probably have to do alot more thinking for this!